# Checkbox change function does not work except clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a function for a hdcheck checkbox.

```
$('#hdcheck').change(function () {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert("It is Checked");
  }
  else {
    alert("It is Unchecked");
  }
});
```

It works find when I check or uncheck the checkbox but I have made a function that problematically make this checkbox checked or unchecked. 
Here is the function on checkbox `chk_1`:

```
$('#chk_1').change(function () {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#hdcheck').prop("checked", true);
  }
  else {
    $('#hdcheck').prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

This function works fine on making the first checkbox (`hdcheck`) checked or unchecked but it does not pop ups the alert message. Mean the function `$('#hdcheck').change(function()` 
does not work.

Answer (score 2):

As you are changing the property programmatically, you should trigger the change event, this is the minified version of your code + a change trigger.

```
$('#chk_1').change(function() {
    $('#hdcheck').prop("checked", this.checked).change();
});
```

This is not a *bug*, this is an expected behavior.

Comment: When I done this, It makes checking and unchecking very slow, about 2 seconds on a check or uncheck click. and It also does not work to trigger the change event.

Comment: @RashidFarooq Can you provide a demo?